# Can I set password hint on linux

Tags: linux, security, password

Is there any standard way to setup user password hints in Linux machine? To later check it out from the console (terminal) login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably write a PAM module to do just that. Of course, anything that could show a per-user message would work, but both `pam_issue` or `pam_motd` only seem to know about global messages.

Though with SSH, you can set a per-user Banner, but I don't think you can make the configuration any cleaner than repeating the same two lines for every user:

```
Match User someuser
    Banner /etc/banners/someuser
Match User otheruser
    Banner /etc/banners/otheruser
```

The banner is if course shown before the first login attempt.

---

As for if you *should* use password hints, I do suspect the answer is "no", since it's too easy to make the whole password guessable if the hint is going to be of any use. ("Security questions" like "your first pet's name" are even worse.) But go ask the nice folks over at [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com) about that, starting with e.g.
[An analysis of storing hints for passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44904/an-analysis-of-storing-hints-for-passwords)